# regex for matching all characters in the string any where

Tags: javascript, string-matching

I need a regex for matching all characters in the string. But it is not matter where that characters.

EG - Input array - [a, b, c]
Following words should match

```
abc
axbxc
cybxbxca
```

But should not match following. Because these words has not all input charters.

```
axbxyz
bxba
```

Comment: This task is not appropriate for regex. You might consider other tools, like `s.count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a regexp like `^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)...`, which you can build dynamically from the input:

```js
const inputArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let re = RegExp('^' + inputArray.map(x => '(?=.*' + x + ')').join(''))

const words = [
    'abc',
    'axbxc',
    'cybxbxca',
    'axbxyz',
    'bxba',
];

console.log(words.map(w => [w, re.test(w)]))
```

If the input can contain regex special symbols, don't forget to escape them properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the matching words:

```js
const inputArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const words = [
  // PASS:
  'abc',
  'axbxc',
  'cybxbxca',

  // FAIL:
  'axbxyz',
  'bxba',
];

const result = words.filter(word => inputArray.every(str => word.includes(str)));
console.log(result); // ["abc", "axbxc", "cybxbxca"]
```

Comment: This may correct, but i need regex.